# mb_strtoupper displaying question mark

Tags: php, uppercase

Hi I'm having a problem converting special characters to upper case.

With regular strtoupper I get something like DANIëL and when applying mb_strtoupper I get DANI?L.
Here's the code:
mb_strtoupper(rtrim($pieces[1], ","), 'UTF-8')

Mind you, I already have this running on the input:
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $tr->TD[0])

Could this be the reason? Or is there something else?

Comment: did you set the internal encoding beforehand? e.g. `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` and, presuming you are rendering html, is the content-type header set (e.g. `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`)?

Comment: You may have a look into the `mb_convert_encoding($str,'UTF-8','Latin1');` (doing from latin1 to utf8)

Comment: mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); and Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8) didn't make a difference.

@Proger_Cbsk To use instead of iconv or with the mb_strtoupper?

Comment: Yes, instead of `iconv` . Anyway, from my experience, special char conversion issue are hard to solve because both php and your browser can be in fault. For your test, you should utterly disable any browser post-process using `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` . Also try to force charset within your browser. Once you're sure your browser is not at fault, come back :)

Answer (score 0):

Typical issue of trying to uppercasing a Latin1 when the converter expect UTF-8

Be sure to check your string source. This sample will works if your text editor works in Latin1 pagecode, and *not* in UTF-8

```
$str = "daniël"; //or your rtrim($pieces[1],",")
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str,'UTF-8','Latin1');
echo mb_strtoupper($str, 'UTF-8');
//will echo DANIËL
```

Comment: Anyway, so the original data comes from 2 XML files. Their coding is set to UTF-8 and mb_detect_encoding says the same.
Data gets put into 2 arrays and those 2 arrays get merge into one for which the names in both arrays are compared after which they get stored in a db.

In all cases the special chars get mangled.
So what should be the proper approach?

Comment: I'd debug the old way, i.e `echo` data at each step in a `Latin-1` webpage' charset (in order to see the Ã© thingy at each utf8 chars).

Comment: Note that with what you're explaining, you should never convert (either iconv or mb_convert_encoding). You can also provide a snippet of your code to see the file i/o , merge, sort and db insertion code.